# Countdown timer shown inside of button in UIAlertController then enable button swift update

Tags: ios, swift4

This is a previous post.  As I am new I can not comment.

Thanks to Muhammad Zeeshan as his aswer worked for me until...

Since the latest swift the code changed.  Now you click the cancel button and get the error Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on line

```
let alertController = presentedViewController as! UIAlertController
```

Actual updated code

```
var timer = Timer()

var timerCount: Int = 5


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func okButton(_ sender: Any) {
      showAlertView()
    }
    func showAlertView() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message of alert", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
        okAction.isEnabled = false

        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true) {
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.countDownTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }

    @objc func countDownTimer() {
        timerCount -= 1

        let alertController = presentedViewController as! UIAlertController
        let okAction = alertController.actions.first

        if timerCount == 0 {
            timer.invalidate()

            okAction?.setValue("Ok", forKey: "title")
            okAction?.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            okAction?.setValue("Ok \(timerCount)", forKey: "title")
        }
    }}
```

So I am wondering how to kill it without the error.

Answer (score 0):

Once I figured out unwrapping an optional it was easy.

Just before

```
let alertController = presentedViewController as! UIAlertController
```

Do

```
if presentedViewController == nil {
       timer.invalidate()
       return
}
```

Also I had to add

```
timerCount = 5
```

before

```
showAlertView()
```

To reset the counter.